# How to make TextView bold using Fontinator library?

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts

I'm using [Fontinator library](https://github.com/svendvd/Fontinator) for custom fonts in android. The documentation says:

> use splited fonts without android:textStyle!

But if I want to make text bold, how it can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Splited fonts mean a font with multiple files like this:

My-font-bold.otf
My-font-regular.otf

For Bold TextViews you have to use My-font-bold.otf and at normal TextViews My-font-regular.otf

If you have only one font file you can use textStyle!